# Is using the shield in a CAT cable for return current a bad idea?

Tags: shielding, poe

Consider a PoE solution that uses shielded CAT cables and where the shield is connected to signal ground on both the [PSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_over_Ethernet) and the [PD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_over_Ethernet) side. In this case, the shield is most probably presenting a lower resistance path than the twisted pairs in the cable, so the DC return current will flow through the shield. Are there any disadvantages with this setup? Should you AC couple the shield to the signal ground to prevent this? Are there any standards or best design practices that address this?

Comment: To emphasize @Justme's good answer.  In general (There are always exceptions), shields, chassis, structures, etc should not carry any power or return currents.  They should only carry leakage, stray, unintended coupling currents, that sort of thing.

Comment: In case of an instrument of some kind with interconnected (power and data) modules, a common ground philosophy is to connect the signal ground to the chassis ground. In this case, the DC return current will inevitable flow through the chassis. In what way is this a bad thing?

Comment: For a couple of reasons.  First, the chassis ground connections are usually not rigorously designed & built.  This means the resistance in that path may not be well defined,  Dissimilar metals and moisture can lead to corrosion.  And using the chassis and shields for return currents can exacerbate radiated emissions, causing you to fail EMC testing,

Comment: Also note that especially in industrial situations, pretty solid differences in local chassis potential are hard to rule out. Do you really want to risk helping the neutral connector on a 63 A device carry current by offering a second path via the ethernet cable?

Comment: Agree when it comes to the chassis. And if you intend to use it for shielding the construction and design is really important. However, my experience is that connecting the 0 V reference on all PCBs in an instrument of some kind (medical, industrial etc.) to the chassis ground yields lower radiated emissions. And my point is that this will lead to DC return currents in the chassis in case the chassis provides a lower resistance path than the 0 V reference wire in a signal or power cable.

Comment: Note that I don't mean that you can omit a dedicated return path. I'm talking about the nature of DC and low frequency signals/currents above. For higher frequency signals you will of course need to provide a tightly coupled return path, no matter if the signal is routed on the PCB or through a cable. Otherwise you will definitely have a lot of radiated emissions.

Comment: @FreddaH As mentioned many times, as per the Ethernet and PoE standards, you can't build an PoE device where PoE return currents flow in the shield. If DC return current flows in the shield, the devices violate the isolation requirement in the standards. So in a properly made PoE device, the shield won't be a return path for PoE currents.

Comment: "the shield is most probably presenting a lower resistance path than the twisted pairs in the cable" -> I believe this question builds on a false premise. Have you actually measured or estimated these two resistances? Usually shielded cable has big twisted pairs, while the shield is just thin mylar or something similar. I would be very surprised if the shield offers a lower resistance.

Comment: @Justme I'm not arguing that you're wrong. I've just briefly looked at 802.3 Clause 33 and Clause 145 and don't understand all the details. The above comments where more of general character discussing how signals and return paths behave and not directly related to PoE.

Comment: @Vladimir Yes, I've measured the DC resistance. A braided well terminated shield has lower DC resistance than a 24 AWG wire in a twisted pair.

Comment: Interesting - did you include the plugs on both ends? and of course you have 4off 24 AWG in parallel. I have used 23 AWG wire only for these kind of things.
Not trying to doubt your numbers or anything I am just surprised - I would have guessed the opposite result.

Answer (score 18):

Yes, it is a bad idea.

The cable shield should not be used as a current conductor.

And as Ethernet is supposed to be a transformer isolated interface, including the PoE part, there should not be any possibility of return current of PoE flowing in the cable shield.

If there is a possibility of return current in the shield, there is likely a design error and device is not compliant with Ethernet or PoE standards. Standard requires 1500 Vrms isolation between PoE voltages and frame ground.

Also, if you require shield as a return path, it will not work with a standard but just non-shielded cable. Also not all cables or devices provide a connection to shield, and in buildings, inside the infrastructure cabling, the shield will be bonded to PE earth/ground, and wall sockets in the room may not provide a connection to the cable shield at all in order not to cause ground loops.

Comment: Isn't the isolation requirement specified like "provide isolation between all accessible external conductors, including frame ground, and all MDI leads"? I cannot see that it says anything about isolation between PoE voltages and frame ground, but I may have misunderstood something. Regarding the return path, I was just pointing out that the DC return current will flow in the shield whether you want it or not unless the shield is left floating or AC coupled to signal ground. Also, I often read that it is a bad idea to use the shield for the return current, but why exactly?

Comment: @FreddaH But the point is on a properly made device there should be no DC return current at all in the shield, not even if you want it. If there is, the PoE device is not made properly. Why? PoE supply and return must go in the MDI data wires, and MDI data wires should have no reference to any exposed circuit, connector, or metal chassis/frame, as the MDI wires must be isolated. Running return currents in the shield is bad because it creates a ground loop and might act as an antenna for all the electrical noise. Also unsafe if you accidentally ground a device only through cable shield.

Answer (score -2):

As I understand, ground loops are not really a problem in small ethernet installations and even less of a problem within a single instrument.

Large industrial ethernet installations on the other hand, where for example two machines are communicating can be a problem if the shield and the PE-ground are connected to the chassis. If the PE-ground differs at the two machines, this will drive a current through the shield. Leaving the shield floating at one end solves this, but effectively creates an antenna instead.

Running current in the shield per se is not a problem. All coaxial cables obviously has the return current in the shield.

Comment: Comparing coaxial to shielded twisted pair makes no sense as they are different to begin with. And in the case of good old 10Base2 coaxial Ethernet, the coax shield is isolated from your PC metal case so it anyway does not apply here.

Comment: The shield is an antenna whether connected at one end or two.  It just changes the frequencies of the set of standing waves that are possible.      Ethernet should never have ground loop issues. It is transformer isolated at each end.

Comment: @RobinIddon The shield of shielded cable is not transformer isolated. If you do connect two desktop PCs together with shielded Ethernet cable, it is very likely that the cable connects the metal chassis grounds together. Which should both be anyway earthed through mains plugs. So there is a ground loop. Ethernet data will still be transformer isolated.

Comment: Running current in the shield is a problem because there should be no DC connection at all between the shield and the PoE supply circuits. So if you got a current flowing through the shield, something is seriously wrong.

Comment: *All coaxial cables obviously has the return current in the shield.* Yeah, but in industrial scenarios the shield must be insulated from the frame just as it is in PoE Ethernet. It must be insulated even if it's just a signal connection. Otherwise you get instant ground loops and radiated emissions and it's a mess. SDI folks have messed up big time on that, thus the "SDI isolator dongle" nonsense. SDI should have been isolated from the get go. Ethernet people have learned that lesson well, and I'm glad, having dealt with a setup full of SDI ground loops. It was awful.

Comment: @justme you are of course right - the shield is a DC connection between whatever you connect it to, including chassis GND.  I never use shielded Ethernet.  So in my mind *unshielded* Ethernet should never have ground loop issues, but that's not what I wrote :-).    I think we're all agreed that whatever the setup, you must not have current flowing in the shield.